# Can not access 3rd level of json for id

Tags: reactjs, json, react-native

i have a flatlist in my app and loading data from json api. Now having this issue that i can not access id of a booking in flatlist keyExtractor. that is why nothing is showing in my flatlist.
Json file:

```json
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "bookings": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "customer_id": 1,
                "driver_id": 1,
                "width": 1,
                "height": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    "message": "Current booking list"
}
```

i can access success like this : `BookingData.success` but i dont know how to pass "id" in keyExtractor to load data in flatlist.

```
<FlatList
  data={BookingData}
  renderItem={renderItem}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.data.bookings[index].id}
/>
```

right now flatlist is not showing any data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass an array as data:

```
<FlatList
  data={BookingData.data.bookings}
  renderItem={renderItem}
/>
```

The `keyExtractor` prop is not needed, as FlatList checks if the items have an `id` attribute already.